# How do I construct this Delphi class in C++Builder?

Tags: delphi, c++builder

What is the C++ equivalent of this code

`ImageEnView1.IEBitmap.VirtualBitmapProvider := TIESlippyMap.Create();`

I get a compile error

> [bcc32 Error] Unit1.cpp(12907): E2285 Could not find a match for 'TIESlippyMap::TIESlippyMap()'

on my code

```
ImageEnview1->IEBitmap->VirtualBitmapProvider = new TIESlippyMap();
```

Comment: You might want to reword your question. You are asking for an equivalent way to write this in C++...  However, I seem to suspect, given your comments, that what you are *really* interested in is how to use TIESlippyMap itself from C++, ie, how "How do I construct a Delphi class in C++Builder?".

Comment: @Arafangion: I changed the title.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Much clearer, thanks.

Comment: When you're trying code and getting a compiler error, it's much better to post that code and the exact error (as you did in a comment later), so that your question is clear. It avoids having people spend time answering you only to find out your question is totally different than it appeared; it also gets you answers that solve your actual problem more quickly. :-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
ImageEnView1->IEBitmap->VirtualBitmapProvider = new TIESlippyMap();
```

**Update:** You are trying to call this constructor:

```
constructor Create(provider:TIESlippyMapProvider = iesmpMapQuest; const cachePath:string = '');
```

The compiler error you are getting means that the C++ compiler cannot find a constructor that has no parameters, or at least a constructor with parameters that all have default values assigned to them.  Depending on which C++Builder version you are using, it is likely that the Delphi compiler included with it is not emitting the default parameter values when generating the C++ .hpp file for the class.  Older Delphi compiler versions did not do that correctly, but newer versions do.  In which case, it sounds like you are using an affected version, so you will have to fill in those parameter values explicitly:

```
ImageEnView1->IEBitmap->VirtualBitmapProvider = new TIESlippyMap(iesmpMapQuest, "");
```

Or else edit the .hpp file to include the default values correctly:

```
class TIESlippyMap : public ...
{
...
public:
    __fastcall TIESlippyMap(TIESlippyMapProvider provider = iesmpMapQuest, const String cachePath = "");
...
};
```